# Overloading >> to work with string class

Tags: c++, c++11

This is part of my header file.

```
#ifndef MY_STRING_H
#define MY_STRING_H

#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class MyString
{
public:

MyString();
MyString(const char[]);
MyString(const MyString&);
~MyString();

private:
char *      pChar;
size_t      NumChars;
size_t      NumSlots;

friend istream &operator >>(istream &,  MyString &);
};

inline istream& operator >>(istream &in,  MyString & Str)
{
in >> Str.pChar;
in >> Str.NumChars;
in >> Str.NumSlots;
return in;
}
```

In my main.cpp im trying to

```
cout << "Enter a string: ";
cin >> Str6;
```

The problems I'm having is, I cant seem to figure out a way to allocate enough space for the new string that is being entered and it also seems to only take the characters up to the first space. so output is like this:

```
Enter a String: does it work?
Your String is: does
```

then i get a wrote to memory after end of heap buffer error pop up.
I was thinking I could use some code from my copy constructor to temporarily build a new Str obj with enough space but I have no idea how to get the character count to make it big enough. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: cin returns whitespace delimited data.  You probably want getline()

Comment: You shouldn't be reading into `pChar` either - it's a character pointer and could be pointing at an existing buffer that's too small for the incoming text (or no buffer at all if you initialise or clear it to `nullptr`).  You also need to clarify your design: your implementation `in >> Str.pChar >> Str.NumChars >> Str.NumSlots;` implies the user's expected to type three things when entering a string, but your `Enter a String: does it work?` example shows that's not how you want it to work.  Either input `NumChars` first so you can allocate accordingly, or read char-by-char growing your buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to address the problem is to change the order of the input. Read `NumChars` before reading data into `pChar`.

```
inline istream& operator >>(istream &in,  MyString & Str)
{
   // Expect the input to be <NumChars> <the characters> <NumSlots> 
   // or
   // Expect the input to be <NumChars> <NumSlots> <the characters>

   // Assumuing the first format...

   // Read the number of characters.
   in >> Str.NumChars;

   // Allocate memory for the characters
   Str.pChar = new [Str.NumChars+1];

   // Skip one character, the separator between <NumChars> and <the characters>
   in.ignore(1);

   // Read the characters.
   for (int i = 0; i < Str.NumChars; ++i )
   {
      Str.pChar[i] = in.get();
   }
   Str.pChar[Str.NumChars] = '\0';

   // Now read NumSlots.
   in >> Str.NumSlots;

   return in;
}
```

I have left out error checking code entirely. In a production program, you'll have to make sure that all the input operations are successful before modifying the object.

Comment: You don't need the `ignore(1)`.  `>>` stops reading when it reaches whitespace, or a character that does not match the data type being read. The next `>>` will skip any leading whitespace before reading the next value. So, take into account that `ignore(1)` would corrupt the data if the user types `5hello` (which is valid when reading an integer first) instead of `5 hello`. Also, you don't need a `in.get()` loop, you can use `in.read(Str.pChar, Str.NumChars)` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, without the `ignore(1)`, the next whitespace will be read into `pChar` whether we use `in.get()` or `in.read()`.

Comment: If you need to skip whitespace manually, use `in >> std::ws` instead of `in.ignore()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, without the whitespace, it is not possible to read a string that starts with a digit.`51road` vs `5 1road`. Use of `in >> std::ws` is also a problem if the first character of `pChar` needs to be a whitespace.

Comment: True, but there is nothing to stop users from omitting the space. You would not be able to differentiate what the users are actually typing when using `>>`. So you need to make it clear to your users what you expect as input.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I hope the OP understands these finer details and uses the approach that best meets their needs.